# Why LeetCode extension can‘t run in Visual Studio Code which on ubuntu 16.04？

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have successfully installed the LeetCode extension and *node.js*，then I click the icon of Switch Endpoint or Sign in that in LeetCode extension ，it reports these error：

> command 'leetcode.toggleLeetCodeCn' not found

or

> command 'leetcode.signin' not found.

I have tried changing the version of *nodejs* and LeetCode extension, but it didn't work. When I reload the *VSCode* window, it would reports this error:

> LeetCode extension needs Node.js installed in environment path

And then I follow the prompts to open the output channel, the OUTPUT  menu show:

> /bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/bin: Permission denied
> Error: The environment doesn't meet requirements.
> Has anyone ever encountered this problem? please help me! thanks.

my software version:

Ubuntu: `16.04  x64`

VScode: `1.52.1 x64`

*nodejs* version which I have tried: `8.9.3/15.6.0/15.10.0`

leetcode extension version which I have tried: `0.16.2/0.17.0`

Comment: Sounds like an abandoned project for months, https://github.com/LeetCode-OpenSource/vscode-leetcode/issues

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs to me. The leetcode plugin worked well in the past weeks, but today, all of sudden, it stopped working

I tried

1. re-intall leetcode cli globally
2. add source .bash_profile and .bashrc to my zshrc
3. update node

However, none of them works.

The problem was resolved by doing the follow

1. disable leetcode plugin
2. reload
3. enable leetcode plugin

Answer (score 0):

I also got this pop-up message on VSCode: "command 'leetcode.signin' not found."

Solution from Conan DING worked for me.

Then I got this message: "LeetCode extension needs Node.js installed in environment path."

Solution: closed VSCode and opened back up using CLI. Now able to sign in.